# Android : Perform a task while application opened for first time alone?

Tags: java, android

I need to create database table when application runs first time after installing. So how to get the status of the application running first time when app is installed? I have heard about SharedPreferences but not familiar with it. Any code help is appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: This is not a valid question !. Android will create the SQLlite database automatically after you called the SQLiteDatabase instance !

Comment: @daigoor: Once the app is installed, then how to create and insert values into the database table on first install alone?

Comment: ok after installing the application you need to open it !. just insert any value you want and the Android OS will handle the creation of the database for you there is no need to create it by your self !! try to search for more resources about using the SQLite databse

Answer (score 3):

[SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) has a onCreate method which gets called if the database does not exist and needs to be created for the first time.

Use this to create and initialise your database with whatever data you need in the tables.

Comment: this is the correct answer if you simply need to create a database on the first run. however if you need other "first run checks" like download something, you should consider SharedPreferences as the OP said

Comment: But i have to insert the value into database table when the app is run for first time after install alone...

Comment: @Raman-Mystry With the onCreate method you can execute any queries you want. First the creation of the tables and then populating the tables with data.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to insert a value in the database on the application first run you can put a value in the sharedPref like this :

```
    private static void SaveBooleanPreferences(String key, boolean value, Context context){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();

    }
    private static boolean getBooleanPreferences(String key, Context context){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);

    }
```

after you detecting the value of the first run try to insert into the database, Android OS will handel the creation of the database for you there are no need to create it by your self !

Comment: +1 for good answer. I've solved this actually by the following code posted here by me... Thank you so much..

Answer (score 1):

I've solved by referring following Code :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean haveWeShownPreferences = prefs.getBoolean("HaveShownPrefs", false);

if (!haveWeShownPreferences) 
{
    // launch the preferences activity

}
else
{
   // we have already shown the preferences activity before
}

SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = prefs1.edit();
ed.putBoolean("HaveShownPrefs", true);
ed.commit();`
```